# Can I change declaration type for a variable in Java?

Tags: java

**Q:** Can I change the declaration type for a variable in Java?

For e.g.,

```
public class Tmp{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Foo";
    s = null; //same Error results whether this line included or not
    int s = 3;
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

But attempted compilation results in the message:

```
Error: variable s is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[])
```

Oddly, re-declaring the type of a variable works just fine in an interactive DrJava session:

```
> String s = "Foo"
> int s = 1
> s
1
```

What's going on?

Comment: No, you cannot redeclare variables.

Comment: What I think may be happening in your DrJava session is either it is seeing you declaring a variable of the same name and placing it in a different scope (as discussed in mprabhat's answer), or it is catching the conflict and scrapping the first declaration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can I change the declaration type for a variable in Java?

No, the compiler knows that `s` already exists within the same scope and is declared of type `String`.

I've never used DrJava before but as an interactive interpreter, it may be able to de-scope the first variable and replace it with the one declared in the new statement.

Answer (score 7):

Variable names inside a scope is fixed, so you cannot have same variable with multiple types. You can have same name with two different type but in a different scope. So below example if you consider is fine since we are changing type in two different scope. One instance level and second time method level.

```
 public class Test {
    private String variable = "";

    private void init() {
        int variable = 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

No.

But you can try something like this

```
public class Tmp 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    {
      String s = "Foo";
      s = null;
    }
    int s = 3;
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

But do you really want this? It can be really confusing for the readers, if the type of a variable changes.

Answer (score 4):

You can not change the declaration of a variable within the same scope.

Since everything in Java is an Object, you can as well declare s as an Object and let it become anything you like...

If drjava allows you to redeclare the variable within the same scope then its behavior is odd. Report the error.

This code should work:

```
Object s;

s="Foo";
System.out.println(s);
s=3;
System.out.println(s);
```