# Declaring variable outside loop and using it in loop

Tags: java

Just can't can't get my head over. Why can't I use datumRodjenja variable in my do while loop or try block?

```
boolean unosDatuma = false;
LocalDate datumRodjenja = null;

    do {
        try {
            String datumRodjenja = sc.nextLine();
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
            return LocalDate.parse(datumRodjenja, formatter);
        } catch (Exception ex1) {
            System.out.println("Neispravan datum: ");
            return unosDatumRodenja(sc);
        }

    } while (unosDatuma == false);
```

Comment: Why are you re-declaring datumRodjenja?. See here on why you cant do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092245/can-i-change-declaration-type-for-a-variable-in-java

Comment: The variable `datumRodjenja` ist already declared outside the block. So it can't bei declared again inside of the try-block. Try using a different name dir the variable.

Comment: Why are you wrapping a loop around logic​that can only possibly execute once?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are declaring variable **datumRodjenja** two times (as **LocalDate** outside do-while and as **String** inside do-while/try) within same scope.

Comment: oh, yeah, that's mistake no1 :D, but the problem remains. 

String datumRodjenja = null;

Comment: delete the line :LocalDate datumRodjenja = null (if not needed).
If needed rename the variable String datumRodjenja with some other name. :)

Answer (score 1):

As other have pointed out, you have a variable conflict.
First, you should use explicit variable names, and use appropriate types.
Second, read again manuals concerning variable scope.

To make it short: a variable declared between {} only exist within these {}.
The following code should be better, but i have not tested it.

Some things are unclear to me with your loop.

I had a teacher that always told use : for better algorithm, write them on paper with human language BEFORE any coding, clearly identify variables, stop conditions etc.

```
// still something unclera in this code ...
boolean unosDatuma = false;
String datumRodjenja = null;
LocalDate myDate;

    do {
        try {
            datumRodjenja = sc.nextLine();
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
            myDate = LocalDate.parse(datumRodjenja, formatter);
            unosDatuma = true; // use a consistent exit loop condition
        } catch (Exception ex1) {
            System.out.println("Neispravan datum: ");
            // IMO you should print the exception too ...
            // exit loop too ?!
        }

    } while (unosDatuma == false); // now this looks useful ...
```

There is something weird to me with your `unosDatuma` variable, that seems useless here : your only loop exit condition is the `return` ...

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the issue is already mentioned in the given answer, I am just trying to correct the way the code is written. Actually the code looks odd. Please make the below corrections.For your logic a loop is not at all needed,you can use an if condition if needed.

```
boolean unosDatuma = false;
LocalDate datumRodjenja = null;

if(!unosDatuma){
    try {
        datumRodjenja = sc.nextLine();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
        return LocalDate.parse(datumRodjenja, formatter);
    } catch (Exception ex1) {
        System.out.println("Neispravan datum: ");
        return unosDatumRodenja(sc);
    }

}
```