# Why casting this variable give me a long data type containing scientific notation?

Tags: java, casting

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     long ageEarth = 4543000000L; 
     System.out.println(ageEarth);

     double ageEarth1 = ageEarth;
     System.out.println(ageEarth1);

     ageEarth1 = (long) ageEarth1;
     System.out.println(ageEarth1) 


}
```

**Playing** around with the value **4543000000** and passing it to **double** and again to **long** gives me,

> scientific notation: 4.543E9

but scientific notation is a point float number, and long only accepts integers, what's going on here?

///////
EDIT:

I apply the code you guys tell me and give us what we expect but:

```
    long ageEarth = 4543000000L; 
    System.out.println(ageEarth);

    double ageEarth1 = ageEarth;
    System.out.println(ageEarth1);

    ageEarth1 = (long) ageEarth1;
    System.out.println(ageEarth1)

    long ageEarth2 = (long) ageEarth1; 
    System.out.println(ageEarth2);
```

I do not understand the 3rd one printed is by `System.out.println(ageEarth1);` this is when is converted to `ageEarth1 = (long) ageEarth1;` it should give a result of an integer right? So why gives still scientific notation?

[image]

What do you mean truncate the data? Correct me, do you refer to corrupt the data?

4.543E9 = 4543000000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ageEarth1` is of type `double`, not `long`.

Converting it to a `long` by casting it will truncate it, but then you store it as a `double`, so it will behave like one when used, because it is a `double`.

If you convert it back and store the data as a `long`, you'll see that it prints as you expect:

```
long ageEarth2 = (long)ageEarth1;
System.out.println(ageEarth2);
```

Comment: Just to reinforce this answer: Try casting the double back to a long: `long ageEarth2 = (long) ageEarth1;`, and then print `ageEarth2`. You will be back where you started: `4543000000`.

Comment: @andrewjames I elaborated to incorporate that.

Comment: A minor note: This isn't casting, it's a _conversion_ (specifically a narrowing conversion), which is a technical point but relevant when discussing the low-level handling of numbers.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- It's a cast that results in a conversion isn't it? I can touch up the language though.

Comment: `(long)` is a cast that results in one of the conversions (the narrowing conversion of double to long), but there are two happening (and it's the widening conversion of long to double that's the surprise here).

Comment: What do you mean truncate? It will corrupt the data? Thanks for the answer! : )

Comment: @Pablo_06 The fractional part is cut off. `4.8` becomes `4`.

Comment: What is the fractional cut off of 543000000 ?

Comment: I do not know what do you mean? I need to study math fractional part for numbers?

Comment: @Pablo_06 That particular number doesn't have a decimal portion. I was just noting what would happen if it did.

Answer (score 1):

After editing the question, the OP asked:

*the 3rd one printed is by System.out.println(ageEarth1); this is when is converted to ageEarth1 = (long) ageEarth1; it should give a result of an integer right? So why gives still scientific notation?*

[image: number listing]

I will try to recap Carcigenicate's answer and elaborate on it. Hope this helps!

I will separate this into 2 parts:

- assignment statements
- print statements (number formatting)

**The Assignment Statements**

Here are the statements (where "A" is for assignment, and "P" is for print):

```
long ageEarth = 4543000000L;        // A1
System.out.println(ageEarth);       // P1

double ageEarth1 = ageEarth;        // A2
System.out.println(ageEarth1);      // P2

ageEarth1 = (long) ageEarth1;       // A3
System.out.println(ageEarth1)       // P3

long ageEarth2 = (long) ageEarth1;  // A4
System.out.println(ageEarth2);      // P4
```

Looking at statement A3, the point to note is that it does not create a new variable - it re-uses the variable from A2: `double ageEarth1`. The end result of A3 is that the variable `ageEarth1` is still a `double`.

***We did not change the variable's data type***.

In fact, the Java compiler [would not let you change it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092245/can-i-change-declaration-type-for-a-variable-in-java) even if you tried.

So, what does that `(long) ageEarth1` do in statement A3? It takes the value stored in `ageEarth1` (from statement A2) and converts it from a `double` storage structure to a `long` storage structure<sup>*</sup>.

But then, as we have already seen, that result is assigned back to the `ageEarth1` variable - which is still a `double`. So the storage is converted back again from `long` to `double`<sup>*</sup>.

**The Print Statements**

Why do these example `float` values use scientific notation when they are displayed by the print statements? This is summarized by the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Float.html#toString(float)) - see the bullet point which starts:

> If m is less than 10<sup>-3</sup> or greater than or equal to 10<sup>7</sup>, then it is represented in so-called "computerized scientific notation."

By contrast the rules for printing a `long` are summarized [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#toString(long)).

<sup>* *Conceptually, at least. Under the covers, the Java implementation may well be smarter than I am suggesting.*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help you all, now I understand:

We can not refactor or change the data type of a variable in a new another statement on the same scope, that's why give me scientific notation, yes casting is working  `(long) ageEarth1` = `4543000000`, but because of the variable `ageEarth1` is type double, it can only support floating-point number, so to satisfy this inherited instance, the variable condition will make the compiler to change it again from the result of casting to long `4543000000` **TO** `4.543E9`.

That's why you tell me I need to create a new variable long, so it can contain the integer `4543000000`, hence the compiler will not change the result of casting to long `4543000000` **TO** `4.543E9` because it satisfies the condition of containing whole numbers.